# Does "being harsh on someone" make sense?

Tags: collocations

Since the meanings of the words harsh and hard are similar but not the same, does "harsh on" make sense?

For example:

> Calm down you shouldn't be too harsh on him.

Comment: Seems fine to me. I would hazard a guess that hard is more common here but I might be wrong.

Comment: It does not. You are *harsh with* or *harsh to* someone, but not *harsh on* someone.

Comment: @FeliniusRex  I have to disagree; it's perfectly fluent to say *harsh on someone*.  For example, [**"You're trying to tell me I was too harsh on him?"**](https://books.google.com/books?id=fSLKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA9&dq=%22harsh+on+him%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-8snWyKjvAhWnmuAKHStQAEkQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg)  and [**We feel it only fair that we be equally harsh on you**](https://books.google.com/books?id=5H9LAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA547&dq=%22harsh+on+you%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_2LuCyajvAhWzGFkFHcSVBG8Q6AEwAXoECAIQAg)

Comment: I agree with @stangdon. It is interesting to see how some people object to this usage, to which I wouldn't give a second thought. I also think the Ngram chart included in the accepted answer is flawed. [This chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=harsh+on+him%2Charsh+to+him%2Charsh+with+him&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) is more objective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Harsh on” may be acceptable, but “harsh to” is far more common.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Harsh+on%2C+harsh+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHarsh%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Charsh%20to%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I think these can have different uses. One is harsh **to** a friend, but harsh **on** their children, for example. (In that case, it's more common to say one is **hard on** their children, but I think harsh works too.)

Comment: @TypeIA I did not say “harsh on” is ungrammatical; I said and provided evidence that it is quite rare.  I am not sure we materially disagree.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I upvoted!

Comment: @TypeIA Ahh. Thank you. I misread the intent of your comment.

Comment: The Ngram chart is not a fair comparison because instances like "harsh to + Verb" such as "seems harsh to say" or "harsh to be", or collocations with nouns where "harsh on" wouldn't be used such as "sounds harsh to our ears" are a thumb on the scale for "harsh to". You need to include a pronoun in the comparison to make it a fair race. Check out [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=harsh+on+him%2Charsh+to+him%2Charsh+with+him&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think anyone would look at you wrong if you said it, but using harsh instead of hard is probably more of a [malapropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism) in most cases. That being said, because English is so fluid, "harsh on" could easily become more normal if it's used more.

Comment: It's not a malapropism, because harsh and hard are synonyms in this particular usage. However, the phrase "hard on" is an idiom with no sensible literal meaning. As such, changing it is understandable, but a bit weird. I wouldn't touch it with a ten-foot rod. :-)